Is there a glab image to use for creating GitLab releases?
In this tutorial which was published an year ago, it is mentioned to use registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest to create a GitLab release. However, in the documentation it is now mentioned that release-cli is in maintenance mode. So, what to use in place of that? Is there an image with glab installed we can use for creating a GitLab release?



How it works today is that GitLab just runs release-cli in a shell for
the presence of the release keyword. In the first iteration we would
not touch this part actually. The release-cli container image would
basically ship with a release-cli shim that would translate the CLI to
glab. This is to preserve backwards compatibility.

Therefore, at the beginning they will change release-cli to migrate release: block to glab release create command internally and step by step, they may remove release: block to force using glab command directly:
release_job:
  image: gitlab/glab:latest
  stage: release
  script:
    - glab release create v1.0.1 --assets-links='
      [
        {
          "name": "Asset1",
          "url":"https://<domain>/some/location/1",
          "link_type": "other",
          "direct_asset_path": "path/to/file"
        }
      ]'

